# Cannot create correct ad hoc build of app

Tags: iphone, distribution, adhoc

I am trying to distribute my application to a beta tester. I believe that I have followed the ad hoc distribution process to a T but I my tester is having issues when trying to install. The error being "Could not install, invalid entitlements" or something to that effect. I have generated a distribution certificate. I have generated a ad hoc provisioning certificate referencing my distribution certificate, my app id, it's marked as an ad hoc distribution and the devices are selected (I regenerated just to be sure). I downloaded the certificate and profile and installed in Xcode and the keychain as needed. My app id in the info.plist is the same as the one in the profile (with the exception of the 10 character Apple generated prefix).

I went to Xcode and created a dist.plist and unchecked the get task allowed value. I created an Ad hoc distribution configuration and set the code signing identity to the one I just down loaded. Build clean. Build and archive. Shared it using Organizer. Emailed the .IPA and the mobileprovision file to the beta tester. It is probably a forest for the trees type of thing.

And that's where my tragic story ends. I've read everything I can find and I appear to be following the steps. Obviously I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

is the 'Application requires iPhone environment' checked in your info.plist?
are you sure you are using correct provision profile?

Comment: I found the the problem, I used the wrong code signing identify when I signed the file in organizer. It was defaulting to my developer, I changed it to my distribution certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the steps you entered has performed correctly, as you already mentioned forest of trees.
**One thing you are missing** is to set the 
**Code signing entitlements in you project's settings**

you have to set its value to your entitlements file name as in your case **dist.plist**

so set **Code signing entitlements** = **dist.plist** in your projects settings.

Wish you good luck!

Comment: I just forgot to mention it. I did that

Comment: invalid entitlements, only occurred with our team in two cases. 1 if get task allowed value remained checked, 2 Code signing entitlements not mentioned in project's build settings. Also make sure distribution provisioning profile is mentioned, and if you are building with correct project build.